# How to filter a query using another query in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

Given the example user and product docs below:

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "_type": "user",
  "_source": {
    "id": "1",
    "following": ["2", "3", ... , "10000"]
}

{
  "_id": "1",
  "_type": "product",
  "_source": {
    "id": "1",
    "owner_id": "2"
}

{
  "_id": "2",
  "_type": "product",
  "_source": {
    "id": "2",
    "owner_id": "10001"
}
```

I want to get the products that belongs to the users who are followed by user with id=1. I don't want to make 2 different queries (first for getting the users followed by user id=1 and then second for getting the products) since user id=1 is following ~10000 users.

Is there any way of getting the result using only one query?

Comment: No. You want a inner join. That's not possible in ES. Check out other options: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `terms` query:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-terms-query.html

Check out their documentation, their example is very similar to your case:

```
GET /product/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "terms" : {
      "owner_id": {
         "index": "<your_index>",
         "type": "user",
         "id": "1",
         "path": "following"
      }
    }
  }
}
```